# This error:" C6262: Function uses '1600000620' bytes of stack: exceeds/analyze:stacksize '16384'. Consider moving some data to heap"

Tags: c++

When I build the code, this run without problems, however I debuging the code, this generate the message: Function uses '1600000620' bytes of stack: exceeds/analyze:stacksize 16384'.

I put the declaration: int array[2000][2000] into int main{} because when int array[2000][2000] was out of int main{}, it generate the error: array is ambiguous.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

/* Function to sort an array using insertion sort*/
void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that aregreater than key, to one 
position aheadof their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key){
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int arr[2000][2000];
int main()
{
    int array[2000][2000];
    int window[9], row = 0, col = 0, numrows = 0, numcols = 0, MAX = 0;
    ifstream infile("phone.jpg");
    stringstream ss;
    string inputLine = "";

    // First line : version
    getline(infile, inputLine);
    if (inputLine.compare("P2") != 0) cerr << "Version error" << endl;
    else cout << "Version : " << inputLine << endl;

    // Continue with a stringstream
    ss << infile.rdbuf();

    // Secondline : size of image
    ss >> numcols >> numrows >> MAX;

    //print total number of rows, columns and maximum intensity of image
    cout << numcols << " columns and " << numrows << " rows" << endl<< 
    "Maximium Intesity "<< MAX <<endl; 

    //Initialize a new array of same size of image with 0
    for (row = 0; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        array[row][0] = 0;
    }
    for (col = 0; col <= numcols; ++col) {
        array[0][col] = 0;
    }

    // Following lines : data
    for (row = 1; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= numcols; ++col)
        {
            //original data store in new array
            ss >> array[row][col];
        }
    }

    // Now print the array to see the result
    for (row = 1; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= numcols; ++col)
        {
        //neighbor pixel values are stored in window including this pixel
            window[0] = array[row - 1][col - 1];
            window[1] = array[row - 1][col];
            window[2] = array[row - 1][col + 1];
            window[3] = array[row][col - 1];
            window[4] = array[row][col];
            window[5] = array[row][col + 1];
            window[6] = array[row + 1][col - 1];
            window[7] = array[row + 1][col];
            window[8] = array[row + 1][col + 1];

            //sort window array
            insertionSort(window, 9);

            //put the median to the new array 
            arr[row][col] = window[4];
        }
    }

    ofstream outfile;

    //new file open to stroe the output image 
    outfile.open("Medianfilter.pnm");
    outfile << "P2" << endl;
    outfile << numcols << " " << numrows << endl;
    outfile << "255" << endl;

    for (row = 1; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= numcols; ++col)
        {
            //store resultant pixel values to the output file
            outfile << arr[row][col] << " ";
        }
    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that this program clear a image, take out noise from images.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what's causing the "array is ambiguous" error. However it's not possible to state this with 100% certainty, so I won't, because your question fails to meet all requirements of a [mre], as explained in the [help]. This huge array is just small enough to fit on the stack during standalone execution, but the additional overhead of debugging blows it past your operating system's limit. Solution: don't put it on the stack. Or use a vector. It's not possible to determine anything else, because of the aforementioned failure to show a [mre]. For more help, see [ask] questions.

Comment: Given the rest of the function, the ambiguity is almost certainly because of `using namespace std;`. A prime reason not to use that is being unaware of what names it brings in and being confused by resulting conflicts.

Comment: 1600000620 bytes of stack space! Now that's Stack Overflow! Seriously, are you sure it wasn't 16000620 which would make more sense.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* example. Certainly you have some includes and other stuff before `main`, right? As suggested by others already, the stuff before `main` *does* make a difference in the behavior of the rest of the program.

Comment: Right, there are also a function before int main. I am sorry, It was my fault. I stumbled with this error before, the trouble was with a Mat matrix.

Comment: `int arr[2000][2000];` adds `2000 * 2000 * sizeof (int)` on the stack... `16000000`. That's is where I would start, since that is roughly 4 times the normal stack space on Linux and 16 times the normal stack space on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the variable array, and put it out of int main{}, before int main{} solve the problem. The ambiguous was caused because array is a class in C++, a and the code before it was being stated how a integer. So change the name array to another any name like arr1 solve the problem.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

/* Function to sort an array using insertion sort*/
void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that aregreater than key, to one position 
 aheadof their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key){
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int arr[2000][2000];
int arr1[2000][2000];
int main()
{

    int window[9], row = 0, col = 0, numrows = 0, numcols = 0, MAX = 0;
    ifstream infile("phone.pmg");
    stringstream ss;
    string inputLine = "";

    // First line : version
    getline(infile, inputLine);
    if (inputLine.compare("P2") != 0) cerr << "Version error" << endl;
    else cout << "Version : " << inputLine << endl;

    // Continue with a stringstream
    ss << infile.rdbuf();

    // Secondline : size of image
    ss >> numcols >> numrows >> MAX;

    //print total number of rows, columns and maximum intensity of image
    cout << numcols << " columns and " << numrows << " rows" << endl<< "Maximium 
    Intesity "<< MAX <<endl; 

    //Initialize a new array of same size of image with 0
    for (row = 0; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        arr1[row][0] = 0;
    }
    for (col = 0; col <= numcols; ++col) {
        arr1[0][col] = 0;
    }

    // Following lines : data
    for (row = 1; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= numcols; ++col)
        {
            //original data store in new array
            ss >> arr1[row][col];
        }
    }

    // Now print the array to see the result
    for (row = 1; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= numcols; ++col)
        {
            //neighbor pixel values are stored in window including this pixel
            window[0] = arr1[row - 1][col - 1];
            window[1] = arr1[row - 1][col];
            window[2] = arr1[row - 1][col + 1];
            window[3] = arr1[row][col - 1];
            window[4] = arr1[row][col];
            window[5] = arr1[row][col + 1];
            window[6] = arr1[row + 1][col - 1];
            window[7] = arr1[row + 1][col];
            window[8] = arr1[row + 1][col + 1];

            //sort window array
            insertionSort(window, 9);

            //put the median to the new array 
            arr[row][col] = window[4];
        }
    }

    ofstream outfile;

    //new file open to stroe the output image 
    outfile.open("Medianfilter.pmn ");
    outfile << "P2" << endl;
    outfile << numcols << " " << numrows << endl;
    outfile << "255" << endl;

    for (row = 1; row <= numrows; ++row)
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= numcols; ++col)
        {
            //store resultant pixel values to the output file
            outfile << arr[row][col] << " ";
        }
    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were unable to move the declaration `int array[2000][2000];` into global scope, because you are using `using namespace std;`.

The `using namespace std;` statement instructs the compiler to import all names found in the namespace `std` into the global namespace, so that you can use them directly (e.g. `string`) instead of accessing them through their namespace (e.g. `std::string`).

This is often discouraged, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), and you have a perfect example of why here.

Since C++11, there is a class template named `array` in the standard library namespace `std`, see [reference for `std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

That means `array` already *may* have a meaning in global scope. Then you try to declare a variable with the name `array` and the compiler doesn't know anymore whether `array` is supposed to refer to the variable you declared or the class template imported from the standard library namespace. Thus the error message.

To resolve this, use a different name for your variable `array`, or better, don't use `using namespace std;` and qualify all your references to the standard library with `std::`.